# How to force Pulumi to create a resource after deleting one

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi

I was trying to rename `aws.lambda.Permission` resource in Pulumi.
It seems that renaming resources is impossible in Pulumi. I don't know the detailed reason, but that's ok.

So, I expected Pulumi to create a new one and delete the existing one. But the problem is that AWS didn't allow us to create a duplicated `Permission` resource with the same content. Therefore, Pulumi failed to create a new one because the new one is just the exactly same `Permission` with a different name.

I think that I need some options to make Pulumi delete the existing one before creating at this point. Does Pulumi provide any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to rename aws.lambda.Permission resource in Pulumi. It seems that renaming resources is impossible in Pulumi. I don't know the detailed reason, but that's ok.

This is a limitation of the cloud provider API. If you want a resource with a new name, you have to create a brand new resource

> So, I expected Pulumi to create a new one and delete the existing one

Pulumi does a create before a delete by default to reduce downtime for objects behind loadbalancers. This us why we recommend using autonaming. See [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/names/) for more information

> I think that I need some options to make Pulumi delete the existing one before creating at this point. Does Pulumi provide any?

Yes, use [deleteBeforeReplace](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/options/deletebeforereplace/)

```
const loggingPermission = new aws.lambda.Permission("loggingPermission", {
    action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "function": loggingFunction.name,
    principal: "logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    sourceArn: pulumi.interpolate`${defaultLogGroup.arn}:*`,
}, { deleteBeforeReplace: true } );
```

Comment: For some reason `deleteBeforeReplace` is not working in case of AWS VPC Endpoints.